# Why the background increase in every click using $(document).height()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the $(document).height() to assign dynamically the height to a background.

Why occurs that when the document is clicked the background image increase it height?
The document height is the same

```
function setDocumentHeight(){
  var height = $(document).height(); console.log("Document Height " + height);
  $(".bg").css({"height":height});
  
}
setDocumentHeight();
  
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (e.button == 0) { setDocumentHeight(); }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jd8n6qa9/

Comment: the height value provided includes the padding, margin and content.

try using innerHeight

Comment: It grows because you added 8px on top. so the document is whatever height + 8, and you set the .bg element to that heigh every time you click. So the .bg element grows by 8, and so does the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set top and bottom 0 to absolute background. it will solve this issue.

```
.bg {top:0;bottom:0;}
```